# Using tkinter to create an ftp app that pulls file from dialog box

Tags: python, tkinter, ftp

I use Filezilla to ftp files all the time at my job. I'm looking to give other people access to ftp files, but we don't want them to have the full access that filezilla gives. I was trying to create a basic python script that would do the following: 
 1. Let a user choose a file from a file dialog box
 2. take that file and upload it to the FTP server 
 3. Throw the user back a message saying, hey your file was uploaded successfully.

I'm able to successfully connect to the FTP server, if I hardcode a file name that's in my python root directory. I'm struggling at passing a function with a parameter to the tkinter button. I want the file to be received by one function and then processed by another. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm a major python noob and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious...

```
import sys
from ftplib import FTP
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
#import Tkinter as ttk

def launch_file_dialog_box():
    raw_filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    return raw_filename


def upload_file_to_FTP(raw_filename):
##    first thing we do is connect to the ftp host
    ftp = FTP('')
    ftp.login( user = '', passwd='')
    ftp.cwd("")
    ftp.set_pasv(False)
    file_name = raw_filename
    file = open(file_name, 'rb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + file_name, file)
    file.quit()



App = Tk()
App.geometry("600x400+200+200")
App.title("Upload a Program Flyer to the Library Website")
Appbutton = Button(text='Choose a File to Upload', command =   launch_file_dialog_box).pack()
Appbutton_FTP = Button(text='Upload File to FTP Server', command =  upload_file_to_FTP(raw_filename)).pack()

App.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

use `self` keyword to use same variable across multiple function definition. create class and then create object later call mainloop()

```
import sys 
from ftplib import FTP
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog

#import Tkinter as ttk

class App(tk.Tk):    
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("600x400+200+200")
        self.title("Upload a Program Flyer to the Library Website")
        self.Appbutton = tk.Button(text='Choose a File to Upload', command = self.launch_file_dialog_box).pack()
        self.Appbutton_FTP = tk.Button(text='Upload File to FTP Server', command =  self.upload_file_to_FTP).pack()
    def launch_file_dialog_box(self):
        self.raw_filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    def upload_file_to_FTP(self):
    ##    first thing we do is connect to the ftp host        
            ftp = FTP('')
            ftp.login( user = '', passwd='')
            ftp.cwd("")
            ftp.set_pasv(False)
            file_name = self.raw_filename
            file = open(file_name, 'rb')
            ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + file_name, file)
            file.quit()
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```